# Limitations with camera and geolocation functionalities

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I am trying to build a plugin in banno plugin toolkit, in which our implementation requires the camera and geolocation access within the plugin, and issue is both are restricted within plugin.

https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/

Is there any work around where i can use camera and geolocation.

Tried to access camera , but didn't worked as it is restricted.

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted in your question, access to Native APIs / operating system APIs is restricted per https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/

> The Plugin Framework does not support accessing native APIs or
> operating system APIs.
>
> So the following are not supported in plugins:
>
> - Geolocation
> - Camera access
> - Microphone
> - Address book / contacts
> - Apple Wallet / Google Wallet
> - Apple Pay / Google Pay

A different section on that page, *"Opening new windows"*, might offer a different option but it wouldn't be exactly what you're asking about:

> An alternative use case is to open an embedded web browser link via the Plugin Bridge

- More on the Plugin Bridge: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/